# clickable cardviews in a fragment within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cardview

I have a side navigation drawer that connects to fragments. In one fragment, I have three CardViews that need to take me to other fragments. All the examples I've seen use RecyclerView with a ViewHolder to implement this, but I am not looking to use RecyclerView on this one. I've tried the following for one of the CardViews, but it does not seem to be working:

```
  public class Dashboard extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener  {
    View view;
    CardView cardview1;


        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView  (LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup
                container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_fragment, container, false);
            cardview1 = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardview_a);
            cardview1.setOnClickListener(this);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            getActivity().setTitle("Title");
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment fragment;
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.cardview_a:
                fragment FragmentA();
                    break;
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Fragment fragment;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.cardview_a:

            fragment = new FragmentA();     
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  
            transaction.replace(R.id.container,fragment);
            transaction.commit();

          break;
        }
    }
```